# How set database config auth in agenda job scheduling library?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, scheduling, job-scheduling

I'm trying to use [agenda](https://github.com/rschmukler/agenda) job scheduling library in my application. And trying to create new Agenda instance like the following:

```
var agenda = new Agenda({db: {address: 'localhost:27017/agenda-example'}});
```

I can't setup connection to my MongoDB instance due auth failing. How could I provide auth options to Agenda?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Agenda is foreign to me but a "[mongo connnection string](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/connection-string/)" accepts username and password.

in your case try

```
mongodb://USERNAME:PASSWORD@localhost:27017/agenda-example
```